# Is it possible to Oversample just one class out of 13?

Tags: text, classification, oversampling

I was wondering if it was possible to perform SMOTE or similar techniques to only one minor class. I have a text classification problem where all minor classes have good accuracies (unique words that differentiate them) except for one class where all the words in it are overlapping with other 13 classes and thus a very low prediction accuracy (31%)
I'm trying to increase the number of samples of only this class!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use synthetic oversampling on a single class. If you just want to reinforce the existing distribution of the minority class SMOTE can help, or if you're more worried about decision surfaces an ensemble of techniques like oversampling with ADASYN and undersampling with Majority Tomek Link removal might be worth trying.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you . I guess ADASYN is all what I need. But how Can I know that my algorithm will perform well on new unseen data if I applied sampling techniques.

Comment: You still need to hold out some of the minority class with the rest in order to test for that purpose